# HANDLER-CASE alternative which is not a macro

Tags: common-lisp

So consider the following code:

```
(define-condition some-condition (error) nil)

(defmethod print-object ((obj some-condition) stream)
  (format stream "HELLO THERE"))

(defmacro error-report-test-aux (fn-to-cause-error error-type-to-catch fn-to-handle-error expected-message)
  `(let ((result-message
           (handler-case (funcall ,fn-to-cause-error)
             (,error-type-to-catch (e) (funcall ,fn-to-handle-error e)))))
     (assert (string= result-message
                      ,expected-message))
     t))
```

I can use it like so:

```
(error-report-test-aux (lambda () (error 'some-condition)) 
                       some-condition 
                       #'princ-to-string 
                       "HELLO THERE")
```

But I wanted to make `error-report-test-aux` a function instead of macro, so that i can pass to it a type of condition within a variable.

To simply write `defun` instead of `defmacro` and remove backquote and commas doesn't work because `handler-case` is macro and it doesn't evaluate `error-type-to-catch`.

**My question is:** Is there something like `handler-case` that would evaluate it's arguments (specifically condition type argument)?

Comment: I don't think passing `nil` as `stream` to `print-object` is compliant code. You probably meant to use `princ-to-string` instead of the `lambda` there.

Comment: You could try using `HANDLER-BIND` to establish a handler for any `CONDITION`, where you then check if the condition is of the right type and decline to handle if it's not.

Comment: @sds Your comment made me read a bunch of CLHS. Now I know more, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no :-)

## *No* to your exact question

There is no *standard* function that would do what you want because catching errors requires establishing bindings and one usually want to bind constant symbols (like in [`let`/`let*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm)) because it is easier to optimize.

You *might* consider creating a "universal" handler using [`handler-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_handle.htm) and then declining to handle "uninteresting" conditions (as suggested by @jkiiski in comments), but I am not sure if that fits your exact requirements (untested!):

```
(defun error-report-test-aux (fn-to-cause-error error-type-to-catch expected-message)
  (catch 'trap
    (handler-bind ((error
                    (lambda (condition)
                      (when (typep condition error-type-to-catch)
                        (throw 'trap (string= (princ-to-string condition)
                                              expected-message))))))
      (funcall fn-to-cause-error))))
```

## *Yes*, implementation-specific

***IF*** your implementation implements [`handler-case`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_hand_1.htm)/[`handler-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_handle.htm) by binding an internal global variable, you can use [`progv`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm) to bind it yourself and thus implement your `error-report-test-aux` as a function.

This is probably not the best idea (your code becomes wedded to a specific implementation).

## *Yes*, kinda

You can use the fact that `some-condition` names a CLOS class and use generic functions instead of the macro.